# How I would Add the Int in this Variable to each int in this list

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, int, ascii, public-key-encryption

I need to add the `int` in `Offset` to each number in `Code`
This is How i made the `Offset`

```
num1 = (randint(33,126))
num2 = (randint(33,126))
num3 = (randint(33,126))
num4 = (randint(33,126))
num5 = (randint(33,126))
num6 = (randint(33,126))
num7 = (randint(33,126))
num8 = (randint(33,126))
key1 = chr(num1)
key2 = chr(num2)
key3 = chr(num3)
key4 = chr(num4)
key5 = chr(num5)
key6 = chr(num6)
key7 = chr(num7)
key8 = chr(num8)
characterkey = (key1 + key2 + key3 + key4 + key5 + key6 + key7 + key8)
Label(window2, text = characterkey, font = font, bg = "Dim grey", fg = "cyan").place(x = 130, y = 300)
offset = int(num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8)
offset = int(offset/8)
offset = int(offset - 32)
print(offset)
```

I have converted a text file into its ASCII Code here

```
Code =" ".join(str(ord(char))for char in readFile)
```

But i need to add the Offset to each Converted Ascii Code in Code and after the offset is added if it equals more then 126 it will minus 94

Comment: Could you *please* use lowercase names for variables (See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do, but here is my guess:

If you want to be able to quickly see what it does:

```python
Code = " ".join(map(str, [char + offset - 94 if char + offset > 126 else char + offset for i in map(ord, readFile)]))
```

Or when you care for speed (because char + offset gets calculated twice in the above example):

```python
Code = " ".join(map(str, [(lambda x: x if x <= 126 else x - 94)(char + Offset)) for char in map(ord, readFile)]))
```